# how to retrieve information from the array

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello I am a beginner in codeigniter framework and I have trouble understanding how to retrieve information from the array that was returned from method.

On my index page i have login form, and when user insert username and password and clicks submit button he calls controller's method login whose task is to collect username and password from form and to pass the data to models method "login($username, $password)" and then models method returns true or false depending on whether we have valid user in database or not, and then controller's method either pass the user further or returns him on the beginning. My problem is that i want to know users access level, and i made this method in model

```
public function users_level($username){

$query = $this->db->get_where('users',array('username' => $username) );

$users_level = $query->result();    // I tried with these too $users_level[] = $query->result();    

return $users_level;
```

}

with which i want to return user's access level, and to use that information in order to determine what view to present for that specific user.

This is login method from controller:

```
public function login(){
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    $this->load->model('model_user');
    $logged_in = $this->model_user->login($username,$password);
    if ($logged_in == true){     
        $result['level'] = $this->model_user->users_level($username);
        $this->welcome($result);                    
    }else if ($logged_in == false){ 
        $this->index();
    }
}
```

And this is my welcome page.

```
<?php
echo "<br/><br/> WELCOME <br/><br/>";

//echo "Users level is : " . $user_level['level'];      //this is problem

?>
<?php  
      print_r($user_level); 

?>
```

And now i don't know how to extract information from that array.
When i do

```
print_r($user_level);
```

to see what is the output, i get this as result:

WELCOME

```
Array ( [level] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 13 [username] => john_username [password] => 123 [name] => john [surname] => johnson [phone] => 123456 [email] => john@gmail.com [level] => 2 [user_type] => professor [activated] => 1 [is_admin] => 0 [is_professor] => 1 [desk] => [academic_year] => 0 [average_grade] => 0 ) ) )
```

and if i try to do something like this :

```
echo "Users level is : " . $user_level['level'];
```

or:

```
echo "Users level is : " . $user_level->level;
```

error occurs:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: views/view_welcome_page.php
```

I understand that this is not an object but i don't know how to retrieve information from column - level from my table? 
thanks in advance

Comment: Your column `level` is 2 levels deep - `$user_level['level'][0]['level']`

Comment: my mistake i am sorry.This solves my problem. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
edit your code in function as
$users_level = $query->result_array(); 

then u will get info like   

$userlevels = Array ( "level" => Array ( "0" => array ( "id" => '13' ) ) );
echo "Users level is : " . $userlevels['level'][0]['id'];
```

Comment: u can get other infomation like same pattern.

Comment: no, when i copy and paste your line this is the error that occurs

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 0

Filename: views/view_welcome_page.php

Comment: hi where r u printing this array, in view file or in controller?

Comment: what is your array in view file, can give u a sample of this?

Answer (score 0):

if you want array (for single row), then edit model like this:

```
$users_level = $query->row_array();
return $users_level;
```

for multiple rows:

```
$query->result_array();
```

Comment: ok i try that but still when i try to do : 

        echo "Users level is : " . $user_level->level; 

the same error occurs: Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: -> means object. with row_array() or result_array() u retrive array. So You should use $user_level['level']